# Stripe maximum data lengths

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's simple 'Checkout', is there a specification detailing the max length of data accepted and returned, eg for the following data:

```
customer id
description
risk level
address_line1
etc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Stripe does not share that data.  The IDs are approximately 16-27 characters in length; however, we usually recommend just setting something much larger in case that changes (eg. 32-64 characters).  The other attributes are less defined.

Comment: About `id`s specifically, [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/forum/#!topic/api-discuss/1F5Wb4HRnNQ) from 2013 states: “We'll soon be increasing the length of most IDs returned by the Stripe API (to around 30 characters). We have deliberately never published
the length of these IDs, but we wanted to let people know in case
they're relying on the existing length. We may vary the length of IDs
in the future, but you can safely assume they'll never exceed 255
characters.”

Comment: Confirming @FabienSnauwaert From the [Stripe API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades): "You can safely assume object IDs we generate will never exceed 255 characters, but you should be able to handle IDs of up to that length. If for example you’re using MySQL, you should store IDs in a `VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin` column (the `COLLATE` configuration ensures case-sensitivity in lookups)."

Comment: The limit for the description of a payment_intent is 1000 currently. I think it depends on the data type. It's best to test it yourself.

Comment: Another factor to maybe keep in mind is the dashboard. e.g.: the `API ID` column for product prices only shows the first 20 characters. So it's a bit more convenient to keep price IDs 20 chars or less.

Answer (score 16):

max length of **customer id** is **255**

max length of **description** is **350** (may change in future)

Copied from the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades),

You can safely assume object IDs we generate will never exceed 255 characters, but you should be able to handle IDs of up to that length. If for example you’re using MySQL, you should store IDs in a `VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_bin` column (the COLLATE configuration ensures case-sensitivity in lookups).

The description field on customer endpoints has a maximum character length limit of 350 now

Comment: The maximum length of payment_method.billing_details.name is 5000 characters.
I don't understand why it's acceptable to have it so long, and why Stripe cannot publish the max lengths of these monstrous fields.

Comment: if using unique indexes in mysql, an important note for mysql version 5.6 and before is your max length can't exceed a length of 191. So if you need to exceed this you'll need to do checks using code.

Comment: @TomAnderson Where did you see that the max-length of `payment_method.billing_details.name`  is 5000 chars? [That isn't mentioned on their `PaymentMethod` documentation at all](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) (as of October 2022).

Comment: @Dai he must have been referring to this API definition: https://github.com/stripe/openapi/blob/master/openapi/spec3.yaml. Indeed here many fields are marked with `maxLength` of 5000.